# How to change permission of spark event log?

Tags: apache-spark, permissions

It seems that the default permission of enent log is 770

```
-rwxrwx---. 1 zht zht 90155 Mar 10 14:19 application_1489126518171_0001
```

I want to change the permission to 775 or 777 automatically

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Unfortunately, it's hard-coded...

Comment: @zsxwing So sad, my situation is that account A setup hadoop&yarn&spark and account B launch spark app  and therefore account B can not access event log because of permission.Is there another way ?

Comment: Add user B to same group as user A